# How to make a servlet's received attributes available to other servlets via the ServletContext's attribute mechanism?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to take in information from servlets using forms and then make the information(Strings) available to other servlets via the ServletContext's attribute method? I do NOT understand this in the slightest and would really appreciate a step-by-step breakdown. Here is my code. One servlet takes an integer and a float and the other a name and surname.

First Servlet

```
package myServlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;


public class FirstServlet extends GenericServlet {

    public String firstName;
    public String surname;

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException{


        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>");
        out.println("ServletResponse");
        out.println("</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
        out.println("<H1>First name: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("firstName") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Surname: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("surname") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Integer: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("integer") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Floating Point:  " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("float") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<br><br><br><a href=\"index.html\">Back to the forms! </a>");
        out.println("</BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
    }
}
```

My Second Servlet

```
package myServlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class SecondServlet extends GenericServlet {
    public String noInteger;
    public String noFloat;


    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException{


        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>");
        out.println("ServletResponse");
        out.println("</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
        out.println("<H1>First name: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("firstName") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Surname: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("surname") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Integer: " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("integer") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<H1>Floating Point:  " + req.getServletContext().getAttribute("float") + "</H1><br>");
        out.println("<br><br><br><a href=\"index.html\">Back to the forms! </a>");
        out.println("</BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
    }
}
```

My Index.html file

```
 <html>
    <head> 
        <title>Lab One</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
            First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"> 
        <br>
            Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"> 
        <br>
        <form action="FirstServlet" method="POST"> 
            <input type ="submit" name="Submit"> </form>
        <br>
            Integer: <input type="text" name="integer"> 
        <br>
            Float: <input type="text" name="float">
        <br>

        <form action="SecondServlet" method="POST"> 
            <input type ="submit" name="Submit2"> </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Your brief isn't correct. You can't put user-specific things into the `ServletContext.` It won't work correctly when you have more than one user. It should go into the session.

Comment: The reason is that there is only one `ServletContext` for the entire application. So putting one user's data into it and expecting another servlet to pull it out intact can only work if there is only one user. There is one session per user. *Ergo* the session is the only sane place to put user data.

Comment: @EJP I updated my code. In this code, I want it to store the last value to be entered so that everytime submit is pressed, it displays the last value to the appropiate place. This is only a tester on Netbeans so only I am using it, on  my own, but it keeps saying null??? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean it keeps *throwing* a `NullPointerException`, at some line of code you haven't told us. Post the stack trace in your question. I'm not interested in helping help you fix code that involves the `ServletContext`, as it is the wrong solution for reasons I have already stated. But your servlets should extend `HttpServlet,` not `GenericServlet.`

Comment: @EJP As I stated before, I HAVE to use generic servlet, it's part of the thing I'm doing, I'm not coding this seriously for an enterprise or something. How do I get the stack trace?

Comment: How do you know you have a 'null'?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add it as a session attribute

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String firstName= (String)request.getAttribute("firstName");
session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
```

then the other servlet/jsp can read the value as

```
session.getAttribute ("firstName");
```

For simplicity you could also set the entire user class (??) as a session attribute

**Edit** as you are using ServletRequest as opposed HttpServletRequest try using the below to get the servletContext

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext()

Comment: I HAVE to use ServletContext. Can you show me that way instead please?

Comment: yes, in your code the variable is called `req` isn't it.

Comment: The servlet context can be obtained by `ServletContext context = req.getSession().getServletContext();`

Comment: Yep, it is, but if I use req.getSession() it says cannot find symbol: Method getSession()....

Comment: I get that, I understand it but what I need to know is HOW to use it so that others can get the attributes?? How will FirstServlet get SecondServlets attributes??????

Comment: The serveltContext is shared between servlets within the same web application.  So if you set an attribute in one servlet, this can be read by another servlet

Comment: So what line do I use in FirstServlet to access SecondServlet's attributes??

Comment: They are session attributes. They are in the session returned by `request.getSession().`

Comment: or in the OP's case `req.getServletContext().getAttribute ("firstName");`

Comment: @EJP I only started this coding today. For the first time in MY LIFE. I don't understand what you say by ServerCOntexts etc etc. And we already established that req.getSession gives an error and this is only for the test end-user, one user. I want to know how if I click on the first submit button, how can I display the attributes in the Integer box??

Comment: `req.getSession()` needs to be changed to `((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession(),`  assuming you don't change the name of your `ServletRequest` parameter from what's shown in your code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Can you explain why my new updated code won't keep hold of old values?

Comment: In your firstServlet, you need to get the values using `String fn = req.getAttribute("firstName");` and then set this value in the session as `req.getServletContext().setAttribute ("firstName", fn);`